# Show/Hide columns based on a column selection

Tags: infopath

I want to display columns based on a specific column selection. I have provided an example below:

There are 3 columns

1. Category (Column1 - dropdown column)
2. Reason for Assumtion (column2)
3. Reason for Dependency (column 3)

The category has 2 dropdown option - Assumption and Dependency.

When I select Assumtion I should have the column2 displayed and hide column 3 and when I select Depenedency I should have column 3 displayed and hide column 2.

How do I do this in InfoPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For hiding controls in Info Path form follow steps below

[**Hide a control based on values on the form**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/infopath-help/hide-a-control-based-on-values-on-the-form-HP010034024.aspx)

1. On the form template, click the control that you want to hide.
2. On the Format menu, click Conditional Formatting.
3. In the Conditional Formatting dialog box, click Add.
4. Under If this condition is true, set the condition that you want.
   For example, to hide the control that you selected in step 1 only
   when a certain value is entered into another control on the form
   template, select that second control in the first box, and then
   specify the value that will determine whether to hide the control
   that you selected in step 1.
5. Under Then apply this formatting, click Hide this control.
6. To save the condition and return to the form template, click OK
   twice.
7. To test your changes, click Preview on the Standard toolbar, or
   press CTRL+SHIFT+B.

Comment: @user34555 if it answers your question please mark as answer as it help other users